# Every other vertex shares $5$ neighbors with fixed vertex

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> An undirected graph has $30$ vertices; one of them is $v$. Each vertex $w\neq v$ shares exactly $5$ neighbors with $v$. Is it true that some vertex must have odd degree?

We could try counting the triples $(v,a,b)$ such that $(v,a),(a,b)$ are edges. Each $b$ yields $5$ vertices $a$, giving $145$ triples, while each $a$ yields $\deg a-1$ triples, giving $\sum_{a\neq v}\deg a-29$ triples, implying
$$\sum_{a\neq v}\deg a=174.$$
But it could still be that $\deg a$ is even for all $a$.

Comment: Since the degree sum formula (also sometimes called the [handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma)) states that,
$$    \sum_{v\in V} \deg(v) = 2|E|, $$

there has to be another vertex with odd degree...

Comment: @Arthur there could be more than one, but it should be an odd number...

Comment: @draks... OK, so you know there is an odd number of edges. The complete graph on three vertices has an odd number of edges, but still all vertices has even degree. How do you prove that there is a vertex with odd degree?

Comment: @Arthur maybe I overlooked something...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume all vertices have even degree.  Then, (a) the set of neighbors, $N$ say, of $v$ has even size, and (b) the vertices outside of $N \cup \{v\}$, call this $M$, has size $29-|N|$, which is odd.

We count the total number of stubs (edge-endpoints) in $N$: if every vertex in $N$ has even degree, the total number of stubs should be even.  We count:

- Each $N$-to-$N$ edge contributes $2$ stubs (an even number in total).
- Each $v$-to-$N$ edge contributes $1$ stub (an even number in total).
- Each $M$-to-$N$ edge contributes $1$ stub (an odd number, $5|M|$, in total).

This gives a contradiction.

This is illustrated below:

[image: illustration]

Answer (score 0):

Let $d_i$ be a degree of vertex $v_i$ in $G=\{v, v_1,v_2,...,v_{29}\}$ and let $N(v) = \{v_1,v_2,...v_k\}$

Make a bipartite graph $H=(A,B)$ where $B=G\setminus \{v\}$ and $$A=\{\{v,v_1\},...,\{v,v_{29}\}\}$$

We connect a pair $\{v,v_i\}$ with $v_j$ iff in a starting graph $G$ $v$ and $v_i$ are neigbours of $v_j$. So in $H$ each pair has degree $5$ and each vertex $v_j$ has degree $d_j-1$ if $j\leq k$ and $0$ if $j>k$. So we have $$\sum _{i=1}^k (d_i-1)= 29\cdot 5$$ or $$\sum _{i=1}^k d_i= 145+k \;\;\;\;(*)$$

- If $k$ is odd, then $v$ has odd degree and we are done.
- If $k$ is even then right side of $(*)$ is odd so if all degrees on the left side are even we get a contradiction. So again some degree is odd again.